# To avoid Criticism

Tags: reference-request, aristotle

“Criticism is something we can avoid easily by saying nothing, doing nothing, and being nothing.” – Aristotle

Does anyone know where (what book) I can find this aristotle quote in?

I've seen some variations of this quote.  This one seems most likely to me to be aristotelian.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems possibly spurious, where did you find this?

Comment: in a movie, and pretty ubiquitous online.  however i have solved my question.  Will post as answer.  If it's pointless, let me know.  I'll delete Q.

Answer (score 3):

It is misattributed to aristotle.  Actually an Elbert Hubbard quote from 
Little Journeys to the Homes of American Statesmen (1898), p. 370

https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Aristotle

Comment: Very nice to learn wikiquote has this resource.